# BigQuery scheduling: Error code 3 : user_id has an invalid value of 0

Tags: google-bigquery

helm me, please. I have the next issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEeeC.png)

Comment: I'm sorry - we can't answer a question that doesn't have a question. Please say way more.

Comment: If this is a bug on something that used to work before, please use the bigquery issue tracker, and make sure to enter details that can help support identify who you are and where you saw the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user_id has an invalid value of 0` message when running a scheduled query in BigQuery happens when the user associated with the scheduled query is no longer active. You can fix it by recreating the scheduled query with another user.

Comment: You can now update credentials from the UI and using bq https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#updating_credentials